# how to check json string values

Tags: android, json, getjson

how to check json strings values,i have 2 json,i want to check the flag equals to "P" or"M"

```
{"page_menu":{"flag":"M"},"menu":[{"pid":"0","name":"Home","refid":"1","ord_field":"1"},{"pid":"0","name":"About Us","refid":"2","ord_field":"2"},{"pid":"0","name":"Services","refid":"3","ord_field":"3"},{"pid":"0","name":"Products","refid":"4","ord_field":"4"}]}


{"page_menu":{"flag":"P"},"page":[{"name":"Home"}]}
```

my code is here.am creating dynamic button with respect to the webservice.here,else part only working.if am clicking the button which consist of child elements its working but other part flag p, page json not working..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 String url = "http://10.0.2.2:80/android_connect/home.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new LongOperation().execute(url);

    }

private class LongOperation  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    private String Content;
    private String Error = null;
    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    String data ="";

    TextView text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    int sizeData = 0;
    private View addButton; 

    protected void onPreExecute() {

         Dialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
         Dialog.show();

          }

    // Call after onPreExecute method
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
            /************ Make Post Call To Web Server ***********/
      BufferedReader reader=null;
              // Send data
            try
            {
                // Defined URL  where to send data
               URL url = new URL(urls[0]);

              // Send POST data request
              URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
              conn.setDoOutput(true);
              OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
              wr.write( data );
              wr.flush();
              // Get the server response
              reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
              String line = null;
                   // Read Server Response
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                           // Append server response in string
                           sb.append(line + "");
                   }

                // Append Server Response To Content String
               Content = sb.toString();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Error = ex.getMessage();
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                           reader.close();
                }
                     catch(Exception ex) {}
            }

          return null;
  }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

        Dialog.dismiss();
              if (Error != null) {
                  text.setText("Output : "+Error);

        } else {


             String OutputData = " ";
            JSONObject jsonResponse;
            //String Data = " ";
            try {

             jsonResponse = new JSONObject(Content);

             JSONObject jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONObject("page_menu");

            String Data = jsonMainNode.getString("flag");



            if(Data.equalsIgnoreCase("P")) 



                  {                                     

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"flag"+Data+"selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();              

                JSONArray jsonMainNode1 = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("page");


               TextView text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

               String strName=text.getText().toString();
               Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),second.class);
                in.putExtra("NAME", strName);
                startActivity(in);



                String Name =jsonMainNode1.toString();

                      OutputData = Name; 
                      text.setText(OutputData);

            }


           else if (Data.equalsIgnoreCase("M"))    

            {                             
                JSONArray jsonMainNode1 = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("menu");

             int lengthJsonArr = jsonMainNode1.length(); 
               for(int i=0; i <lengthJsonArr; i++)
              {                                     
                  JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode1.getJSONObject(i);


                      String Pid      = jsonChildNode.optString("pid".toString());
                      String Name     = jsonChildNode.optString("name").toString();
                      String Refid=jsonChildNode.optString("refid".toString());
                      OutputData = Name;  

                 LinearLayout buttonContainer=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.btn_container);
               Button button = new Button(buttonContainer.getContext());
               button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
               button.setText(OutputData);
               button.setTag(Refid);
               buttonContainer.addView(button);         
               button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(View v) {
                           LinearLayout buttonContainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.btn_container);
                           buttonContainer.removeAllViews();
                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "button" +v.getTag()+ "is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                           new LongOperation().execute("http://10.0.2.2:80/android_connect/home.php?pid="+v.getTag());                        }
                  }
                   );

              }
            }
            }
           //if closing bracket                       
            catch (JSONException e) {

                  e.printStackTrace();
               }

             }

    }

    }
```

logCat is here

```
01-28 04:23:53.522: D/AndroidRuntime(4112): Shutting down VM
01-28 04:23:53.522: W/dalvikvm(4112): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
01-28 04:23:53.552: E/AndroidRuntime(4112): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 04:23:53.552: E/AndroidRuntime(4112): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-28 04:23:53.552: E/AndroidRuntime(4112):     at com.example.proj2.MainActivity$LongOperation.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:161)
01-28 04:23:53.552: E/AndroidRuntime(4112):     at com.example.proj2.MainActivity$LongOperation.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
01-28 04:23:53.552: E/AndroidRuntime(4112):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
01-28 04:23:53.552: E/AndroidRuntime(4112):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
01-28 04:23:53.552: E/AndroidRuntime(4112):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
01-28 04:23:53.552: E/AndroidRuntime(4112):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-28 04:23:53.552: E/AndroidRuntime(4112):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-28 04:23:53.552: E/AndroidRuntime(4112):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-28 04:23:53.552: E/AndroidRuntime(4112):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 04:23:53.552: E/AndroidRuntime(4112):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-28 04:23:53.552: E/AndroidRuntime(4112):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-28 04:23:53.552: E/AndroidRuntime(4112):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-28 04:23:53.552: E/AndroidRuntime(4112):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

after updated also am getting error..

```
    01-28 05:56:33.512: W/dalvikvm(4763): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
01-28 05:56:33.532: E/AndroidRuntime(4763): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 05:56:33.532: E/AndroidRuntime(4763): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-28 05:56:33.532: E/AndroidRuntime(4763):     at com.example.proj2.MainActivity$LongOperation.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:162)
01-28 05:56:33.532: E/AndroidRuntime(4763):     at com.example.proj2.MainActivity$LongOperation.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
01-28 05:56:33.532: E/AndroidRuntime(4763):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
01-28 05:56:33.532: E/AndroidRuntime(4763):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
01-28 05:56:33.532: E/AndroidRuntime(4763):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
01-28 05:56:33.532: E/AndroidRuntime(4763):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-28 05:56:33.532: E/AndroidRuntime(4763):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-28 05:56:33.532: E/AndroidRuntime(4763):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-28 05:56:33.532: E/AndroidRuntime(4763):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 05:56:33.532: E/AndroidRuntime(4763):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-28 05:56:33.532: E/AndroidRuntime(4763):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-28 05:56:33.532: E/AndroidRuntime(4763):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-28 05:56:33.532: E/AndroidRuntime(4763):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check Gson parser: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: @williams JSONObject jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONObject("page_menu");
                      
             String Data = jsonMainNode.getString("flag");
    if(Data.equals("P"))
    {
    //...
    }
    else
    {
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   JSONObject jo = new JSONObject("page_menu");
   String flag= jo.optJSONObject("flag");
   if(flag.equalsIgnoreCase("P")) 
    {
       JSONArray resultarr = jo.getJSONArray("page");
       for (int i = 0; i < resultarr.length(); i++) 
        {
        String namevalue= resultarr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
        }
     }
    else if if(flag.equalsIgnoreCase("M")) 
    {
       JSONArray results = jo.getJSONArray("menu"); 
        for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) 
        {
        String Idvalue= results.getJSONObject(i).getString("pid");

        }
      }
```

Comment: am getting error nullpointerexception.

Comment: Update your question with the code and error.

Comment: @ammu Where is your logcat ?

Comment: @Grishnu that also added now

Comment: Which is your line 161 ? @ammu

Comment: @Grishnu  TextView text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

Comment: Initialize your `TextView` in your `onCreate()` method after your setContentView method.

Comment: @Grishnu after also am getting the same

Comment: Have you set any text in your `TextView`? In your `Intent` besides using `getApplicationContext()` use `MainActivity.this`

Comment: @Grishnu yes..i got..thank you very much for spending your valuable time

Comment: @ammu Awesome :) Enjoy and all the best !!